# Port needed to connect to Azure Analysis Services

Tags: azure-analysis-services

Many corporate networks are pretty locked down other than port 80 and port 443 outbound. What ports are needed to connect to Azure Analysis Services? I'm hoping the answer is 443, but I just want to double check it's not 2383. I didn't spot this in the documentation, but maybe I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the connectivity is done using 80/443
thx